# Camera doesn't create file for GetBitmap or BitmapFactory to review

Tags: android, android-camera, android-contentprovider

**Short Version**

For this line of code:

```
//mImageBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, mUri);
//Altered at the advice of CommonsWare
Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mUri);
```

I receive back the exception: `E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

**Longer version**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    static final String EX_TAG = "Exception";
    static final String ACT_TAG = "Action";
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private String mUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPreview);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
        }
    }

    protected void onClick(View view) {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.i(EX_TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(ex));
            }

            if (photoFile != null) {
                cameraIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", photoFile);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
                mUri = photoUri.toString(); // content://com.suamere.phototaker.provider/external_files/Pictures/JPEG_20180128_081539_1869847943162210201.jpg
                try {
                    Log.i(ACT_TAG, "startActivityForResult");
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.i(EX_TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(ex));
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.ENGLISH).format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        return File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                Log.i(ACT_TAG, mUri); // content://com.suamere.phototaker.provider/external_files/Pictures/JPEG_20180128_081539_1869847943162210201.jpg
                Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mUri);
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.i(EX_TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(ex));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
</application>
```

When I click the button, the camera comes up.  I take a photo and return to my activity.  onResultActivity, requestCode is 1 and resultCode is -1, as expected.  And the uri is an expected path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly the file exists. Your code does not actually use the file, and you are not passing it via `EXTRA_OUTPUT` to the camera app, but perhaps that code is just missing from your question.

Beyond that:

- `mCurrentPhotoPath` is a path, not a `Uri`, and so `Uri.parse()` will not work well.
- Use `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()`, not `MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap()`, to load a bitmap from a file. Or, better yet, use an image-loading library, like Glide or Picasso, so that you can load the image easily on a background thread, rather than freezing your UI as you are attempting to do now.

FWIW, [here is a complete sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.9/Camera/FileProvider) showing using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` with `EXTRA_OUTPUT`.

**UPDATE**

```
Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mUri);
```

`mUri` is a `Uri`. It is not a file. Pass in the path to the `File`. You would get it by holding onto the `File` returned by `createImageFile()`.

Comment: Thanks, Commons.  I have spent a lot of time with my code, including changing getBitmap to BitmapFactory.decodeFile().  The same **ROOT Problem** still seems to exist, that the file isn't being created.  So BitmapFactory has no file to decode.: `E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: content:/com.webfletch.receiptcapture.provider/external_files/Pictures/....jpg (No such file or directory)`.  I updated my question with the altered code and added my manifest.

Comment: Perfect update.  Thank you for pointing that out.  That was indeed the issue.